# Is there any way to show full news article in android studio using newsapi?

Tags: android, android-studio

As a beginner I am making news app. And for that I am using news api.

I am being able to show title, date, and source.

But I want to add a functionality that when someone clicks on a news item title - the *whole* news article displays in the app.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Isn't your news API return that type of data?

Comment: Actually i am beginner,so I don't know to show whole news article if it can be returned

Comment: So I need help and if u can pls help.

Comment: Which API do you use for picking up news ?

Comment: It is newsapi.org

Comment: They seem that they don't support article content, and you've to go through its URL; you can try to use a `WebView` to display the entire page in your app